# How can I query info from a special table structure in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I got a problem with a query or a table in MySQL and i spent so much time to solve it, but i still have no answer. So i need your help.

The format of the table is something like that

```
-------------------------------------------------------------
col1   |   col2   |   col3   |   col4  |  col5   |   col6   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
   a   |     b    |    c     | null    |   null  |   null   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
 null  |   null   |   null   |   1     |    2    |    3     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
  null |   null   |   null   |   4     |    5    |    6     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
  null |   null   |   null   |   7     |    8    |    9     |
-------------------------------------------------------------
  d    |    e     |    f     |   null  |   null  |   null   |
-------------------------------------------------------------
  null |   null   |   null   |   10    |   11    |    12    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
  null |   null   |   null   |   13    |   14    |    15    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
  null |   null   |   null   |   16    |   17    |    18    |
-------------------------------------------------------------
...
```

The table has a structure like that because it loads data from a big-size csv file (about 300k lines). All i want is write a mysql statement that query records in the fastest time that it can and its result is in format:

(a,b,c,1,2,3),(a,b,c,4,5,6),(a,b,c,7,8,9),(d,e,f,10,11,12),(d,e,f,13,14,15),(d,e,f,16,17,18) ...

But ... how? Please help me to solve the problem.
Thks in advance

Comment: You'd be better off massaging the data client-side, rather than trying to come up with a query that has to both look FORWARD (for the 1,2,3 value) and BACKWARD.

Comment: Thks for commenting. But the problem is it must load data from big size csv file to that mysql table (for the fastest performance) and my task is getting info from this table structure for the client module. The number of the records is bigger than above many times. :(

Comment: That's fine, but I'm saying that after loading the .csv into the table, you should run another query that loops over the lable, row-by-row, and fills in the missing data. While it's a bit tedious to create a query that can look "back" to fill in missing data (so the a,b,c values get carried forward into the rows they're missing), it's very difficult to make a query that can look FORWARD, so the missing nulls on the a,b,c row get filled in.

Comment: It's a good solution and i tried before but the difficulty is the time for querying (i have to process 300k lines :(). Do you have any suggest for that statement? (i used cursor, but it was ineffective)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks ugly, but works.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
    IF(col1 IS NULL,@c1,@c1:=col1) AS col1, 
    IF(col2 IS NULL,@c2,@c2:=col2) AS col2, 
    IF(col3 IS NULL,@c3,@c3:=col3) AS col3, 
    col4, col5, col6
FROM
    [table name],
    ( SELECT @c1:=0, @c2:=0, @c3:=0 ) x 
) y WHERE col4 IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: +1 Yes, that's so good. But when query the very lots of records, is it optimum? Thank you very much, however. :D

Comment: You used variable in above query. But if i want to create a view from that one, what solution is? The view in mySQL does not support subquery and variable

Comment: I can't imagine a query without subquery and variable. In your case, It looks like you have to change them before inserting into database.

Comment: In mySQL, the view is such like that. I used load data infile and select out file in my case. But thks anyway, Iqez.

Comment: @DzungNguyen Thanks a lot. I wish my answer was helpful for you.